# How can I use Material RadioButton in iOS as Right to left?

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button, right-to-left, material-swift

I use [Material](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Material) pod library for adding **radioButton** to iOS app.
but it has an issue in right to left languages. it's label shows on right and I wondering if there is a way to put its label to left of radioIcon. here is my code:

```
    rdGroup = RadioButtonGroup()
    
    let rd1 = RadioButton()
    rd1.title = "My Right to left title"
    rd1.isSelected = true
    rdGroup!.buttons.append(rd1)
    
    let rd2 = RadioButton()
    rd2.title = "My Right to left title"
    rdGroup!.buttons.append(rd2)
```

Answer (score 1):

After browsing source code of [Material](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Material) I found out that it's a Button.
Then should just use this:

```
rd1.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
rd1.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

on each radioItem.

happy coding ;)